# Open a file based on date, paste data, save as new date and close

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I need to copy some data every month, paste it into a spreadsheet and then save it as a new file with updated date. I need the macro to look to see if A6 is empty, then select all data from A6 down, which I think is done with the If Not statement.

Once done I need to open a spreadsheet that is saved in the format "Filepath/mmyy Filename.xls"

The sheet I need opening will be last months so I need it to select that month, and then the year in the format yy.

I will also need it to clear the sheet in a certain range and then paste in the data from the first workbook, then Save As with an updated date as mmyy with this months date.

How do I set my code to open the file based on mmyy, and then save as and close? And can this all be done in the IF statement I have opened?

```
Sub Test()

Dim wksht As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range

Set wksht = Sheets("Birse CH")
Set rng = wksht.Range("A5")
If Not IsEmpty(rng.Offset(1, 0)) Then
    Set rng = Range(rng.End(xlDown).Offset(0, 14), rng.Offset(1, 0))
Selection.Copy
'opening workbook
Workbooks.Open Filename:="H:\Finance\CBF\Invoices\Monthly Invoicing Summary\" & Year(Date) & "\ASM\" & (Now(mm) - 1) & Now(yy) & " ASM CBF Reg Summary.xlsx"
Selection.Paste

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! So, what's the question? Please don't just dump all your code in your question. Instead, just include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry was in a rush when typing and didn't take the care needed! I've edited the question to better explain the purpose and changed the code

Comment: I'm looking pretty hard, but I still don't see a question.

Comment: Sorry! How do I set my code to open the file based on mmyy, and then save as and close? And can this all be done in the IF statement I have opened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [`Format` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251755%28v=office.15%29.aspx).

```
Format(Now, "mmyy")
```

returns `0914` at the time of writing.

However, it looks like you want to subtract one month from today's date. This will do the trick:

```
Format(DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now) - 1, 1), "mmyy")
```

which should replace `(Now(mm) - 1) & Now(yy)` which won't compile because that's [not how `Now` works](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278671%28v=office.15%29.aspx).

To [`SaveAs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185%28v=office.15%29.aspx) and [`Close`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838613%28v=office.15%29.aspx), it's easiest to first set a reference to the workbook you're opening:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="...somewhere...")
'... do stuff to the workbook
wb.SaveAs Filename:="...somewhere else..."
wb.Close
```

Comment: Thanks, and what if I need it to return last months date? 

And also, I can't find the saveas function on google? Everyone seems to using a lot more dims and code, is there a simple way to save as and then close?

Comment: Its giving me a compile error and highlighting the word Filename.
`Expected: end of statement`
I have the below
`Set wb = Workbooks.Open Filename:="H:\Finance\CBF\Invoices\Monthly Invoicing Summary\" & Format(Now, "yyyy") & "\ASM\" & Format(DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now) - 1, Day(Now)), "mmyy") & " ASM CBF Reg Summary.xlsx"`

Comment: You need parentheses `()`: `Workbooks.Open(Filename:="...")`

Comment: It's now flagging for `Duplicate Declaration in current scope`, I have a `Dim wksht As Worksheet`, is this affecting the workbook?

Comment: No it doesn't. What does it highlight when it says that? Look, this is growing beyond what can be addressed blindly in a comment. I suggest you ask a new question, showing exactly what is going on. The solution I suggest in my answer works fine, so from now on it's just a question of debugging your attempt to replicate it.